# WPF - How to run a method of a custom control from a view model?

Tags: wpf, methods, command, controls

I work on a custom WPF Diagram Control. The control has a method that arranges the elements in the Diagram and I need to add MVVM support to call this method from my View Model.
At the moment I am a bit confused how to implement this and I hope that someome can point me to the right direction.

Comment: The best way to implement such `ViewModel` <-> `UserControl` _relationship_ would be to add `DependencyProperty` and bind it to a property from `VM`. Please provide code sample/investigation what you've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rethink your concept. What needs to be re-aranged? 
Think of ViewModel the logic behind a view and the view should be as dump as possible without any logic. 
I assume also that the "arranges" method should be well tested and this could also be "easier" done on a `ViewModel` (if done right). Your best bet would be to place all logic in the ViewModel.

From the top of my head I could think of a `DiagramViewModel` with an `ObservableCollection<ShapeViewModel>`. ShapeViewModel can either be a base class or a concrete class which could also have some information about the location of the shape etc. The communication between the view models can be done via a Messenger (MVVM Light Messenger) or EventAggregator https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx.

If you still want to leave your architecture as you have it and want to execute a method on the view I would abstract it in a service. IDiagramUpdateService.
Look at following article which gives you good insights in communication between views and view models (and vice versa).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx
You'll find great information for both approaches.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response to my question.
I think my concept was a bit wrong, since the ViewModel should have no reference to the View.

What I would like to achieve is that I can place a button in the Main Window that calls the Arrange Method in the Custom Control.

I realized this by adding a RoutedCommand to my Custom Control.
And the Command Property of the button on the main window is bound to this RoutedCommand.

So the ViewModel is no longer involved in calling this method. It just manages the items that are shown in the Custom Control.